# Unable to boot into Ubuntu 10-04

Tags: boot-failure

Had to switch off computer when Ubuntu locked up completely (No mouse or keyboard operation).
 Whwn rebooting various messages appeared mainly saying no such file or directory. The target file system doesn't have /sbin/init.
Tried using original CD to view files, but Ubunti-1004 would not mount.
The followig error messages appeared: 
Error mounting:wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda 1
missing codepage or helper program, or other error. In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg|tail or so.
Can I recover at least my files?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer at : http://codeabout.wordpress.com/2011/03/05/fix-your-non-bootable-linux-partition/.
I loaded the original Ubuntu 1004 CD using the temporary version on the disk and then opened the terminal.
After checking the name of the Boot Partition (sudo fdisk -l) this confirmed it as :  /dev/sda1. (The computer only used the one operating system).
I then used the command:  sudo fsck /dev/sda1
This produced a couple of error messages to which I answered "Yes"
e.g. Force rewrite  - Yes
I then rebooted and Ubuntu 1004 loaded correctly.
I hope this may be of help to others who cannot boot up after a forced switch-off of the computer.